# Services in new scope act like transient services

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, object-lifetime

I have a method where I need a new scope (must be a new scope, the scenario here doesn't need it, but when this works I'll use the logic elsewhere where it needs to be a separate scope), for this I use the IServiceScopeFactory (I think that's the right one). I then get the services I need out of the new scope and I expect them to still work in a scoped way. But dependencies in those services act like transient services. I always get a new one in the constructor.

Example:

```cs
public class EntryController : IEntryController
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private readonly IRequestContext _requestContext;
    
    public EntryController(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public async Task GetEntries(int userId)
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var requestContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestContext>();
        var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEntryManager>();

        var test = requestContext // Completely new IRequestContext
        requestContext = _requestContext;
        var test1 = requestContext // test1 is the same as _requestContext, which is good

        return await manager.GetAll();
    }
}
public class EntryManager : IEntryManager
{
    private readonly IEntryResource _entryResource;
    private readonly IRequestContext _requestContext;

    public EntryManager (IEntryResource entryResource, IRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        _entryResource = entryResource;
        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public async Task GetAll()
    {
        var test = _requestContext; // Completely new IRequestContext, which is bad
        return await _entryResource.GetAll();
    }
}
public class EntryResource : IEntryResource
{
    private readonly IRequestContext _requestContext;

    public EntryManager (IRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public async Task GetAll()
    {
        var test = _requestContext; // Completely new IRequestContext, which is bad
        // here is some code for the db query where I need info stored in the IRequestContext
        return _dbContext.Entries.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I understand why I get a new requestContext in the new scope, but when I update the values I would expect those to be available inside the whole scope through dependency injection. When I run the code without a new scope everything works fine. All services are added as scoped services in the startup.

```cs
services.AddScoped<IRequestContext, RequestContext>();
services.AddScoped<IEntryManager,EntryManager>();
services.AddScoped<IEntryResource, EntryResource>();
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates how your services are registered.

Comment: If you registered `IRequestContext` as transient, you will always get a new instance when requested from a scope. That's by design. If you want one instance per scope, you need to register `IRequestContext` as scoped.

Comment: I just added the line I use in the startup.cs to register IRequestContext as scoped. (at the bottom of the question)

Comment: Assuming your controller is transient...what's IEntryResource registered as? So your instance of _requestContext inside the controller is correct? How are you determining it's a new instance or reusing the existing?

Comment: IEntryResource and IEntryManager are both scoped as well, everything is set as scoped in the startup.cs. I would assume that the new scope creates new instances of all scoped services. But then I would expect all requestContexts used in the manager and resource (inside the using) to be one single scoped instance. So I expect a new instance right when I do ```.CreateScope()``` and then it would reuse the same in the whole new scope.

Comment: If everything is scoped then you don't need a scope factory. Just use the injected instance from the constructor.

Comment: Yes, but I need this to work inside a new scope, when this piece of code works I'll use it somewhere else where it must run in a new scope. The snippet above is to test is more easily. It will be used in a graphQL API with a parallell execution strategy. But it's easier to test it in a separate controller for now.

Comment: [Unable to repro](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MLOXph)

Comment: Aha, I modified your code to look more like mine and I think I found something. When I do ```requestContext = _requestContext``` like in my code in the question, it doesn't work. But when I do a single property: ```requestContext.Id = _requestContext.Id``` it works. I will test it further in my code and post the answer here if it works.  My fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gKjthI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue:

```
requestContext = _requestContext;
```

This didn't work because `requestContext` is no longer the same object as it was before this line and it will no longer be the same as the one injected to the other services within the scope.

If I simply assign new values to its properties it does work.
this is why this works:

```
requestContext.Id = _requestContext.Id
```

That way it still is the same object and the new value of `Id` can be retrieved everywhere in the new scope inside the `requestContext`.

With a custom extension I can assign all properties.

```
public static IRequestContext CopyRC(this IRequestContext dest, IRequestContext source)
{
    var props = typeof(RequestContext).GetProperties();
            
    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(source);
        prop.SetValue(dest, value);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

With this

```
requestContext = _requestContext;
```

now becomes

```
requestContext.CopyRC(_requestContext);
```

Thanks to [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) for helping me look in the right direction with his working snippet.